# ProxyChains is redirecting packets destined to local machine to the proxy server

Tags: proxy, port, squid

I am using ProxyChains to connect to my proxy at college. It works very fine except that it even redirects packets meant for a local port to the proxy server :

|S-chain|-<>-172.22.2.211:3128-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK

|S-chain|-<>-172.22.2.211:3128-<><>-127.0.0.1:57343-<--denied

Is there any way to add an exception for 127.0.0.1 in ProxyChains

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following [patch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proxychains/forums/forum/644747/topic/1718334) has been included in [this fork](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains).

Build with

```
git clone https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains
cd proxychains
git checkout v4.5
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo rm /usr/local/etc/proxychains.conf
```

Create the following config file in `/etc/proxychains.conf`:

```
strict_chain
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
[ProxyList]
socks4 127.0.0.1 8080
```

(See `src/proxychains.conf` for a commented example).

Start the SOCKS proxy on local port 8080 to send traffic via a proxy-free server:

```
ssh -D 8080 -f -C -q -N <proxy-free server>
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.